# View ignores Shape of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a `LinearLayout` and some `Views` inside of it.

The `LinearLayout` has the following background-drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#25000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

So my Layout has some rounded corners.

Now I like to set the background-color of my views inside of my LinearLayout and here is the problem:
The background is not within the shape... It ignores the radius of the corner from my LinearLayout. The View should stick to the same size the LinearLayout has. There shouldn't be something "over" this layout.

How can I manage this? I don't want to apply the same background-drawable (same shape) to my View... I think this is not the way I should do this...

Cheers

Layout:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
    android:stretchColumns="*">
</TableLayout>
```

I'm adding the Views programatically (they belong to Fragments):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
    TableRow row = tableRows.get(i % tableRows.size());
    AnswerFragment fragment = answers.get(i).getViewFragment();
    answerFragments.add(fragment);
    transaction.add(row.getId(), fragment);
}
transaction.commit();
```

where tableRows is created by:

```
int rows = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(answers.size())); // n x n
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
row.setId(1337 + i);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tableRows.add(row);
tableLayout.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: post your layout code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding or margin to place your View inside the LinearLayout like you need it to be.

Comment: Hey, sorry this is not what I like to have. The background of my views should fit into the Layout. If the Layout has rounded corners the views of my layout should have rounded corners as well...

Comment: Then you need to apply rounded corners to each of your views inside the LinearLayout as well. The background of the LinearLayout has nothing to do with the children views' background that are placed inside it. Those two are independent.

Comment: This is really complicated though... I would have to check whether the view is on the side or in the middle of the grid... because only the first and last element of each row is affected... and if I change the drawable of the Layout, I would have to change the layout of the child-elements... That doesn't look correct...

Comment: Furthermore I'm animating the background-color of the view within the Layout... I really need to crop the view so that it fits the layout :(

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to handle your corner cases (top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right) layout of the child views inside your LinearLayout differently than that of the other views. It's either that or pad your LinearLayout such that the child views all sit properly enough inside it such that the rounded corner of your LinearLayout does not get compromised. Your choice. But there's no easier alternative where the children Views background-drawable automatically takes the shape of their parent. Atleast as far i know, there is not such a provision.